# Algorithm with $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space to compare two arrays

Tags: algorithms, arrays

$A$ and $B$ are two arrays with $n$ elements each in the range $1$ to $n^2$.

1.How to check if the elements of $A$ are distinct in $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space

2.How to check if $A$ and $B$ have a common element in $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space.

Both the algorithms shouldn't use Hash sets or any other advanced data structure. A and B are just simple Arrays.

Comment: Hint: A number in the range $0$ to $n^2-1$ can be thought of as a two-digit number in base $n$.

Comment: Also note that 2 almost gives you the answer for 1 if you take $B$ "similar to" $A$.

Comment: In which model?

Comment: Are you confident the can be don in O(n)?

Comment: No, I need to know if they can be done?

Answer (score 2):

A HashSet can store $n$ elements in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ space and add/query elements in amortized $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time. Therefore we can use the following approaches:

**1. Are A's values distinct?**

```
HashSet setA;
for i in {1, ..., n}
    if setA.contains(A[i])
        return "No, A[i] is a duplicate.";
    endif
    setA.add(A[i])
endfor
return "Yes, values are distinct.";
```

**2. Do A and B intersect?**

```
HashSet setA, setB;
for i in {1, ..., n}
    if setB.contains(A[i]) or setA.contains(B[i])
        return "Yes, A and B intersect.";
    endif
    setA.add(A[i]);
    setB.add(B[i]);
endfor
return "No, A and B are disjoint.";
```

**Edit:** Thanks to D'Nabre for pointing out a problem. The assumed $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for querying the HashSets may not work out in this case. D'Nabre also pointed at the [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), which is worth a look. From Wikipedia:

> it may also be solved in linear expected time by a randomized algorithm that inserts each item into a hash table and compares only those elements that are placed in the same hash table cell.

Comment: Since I am not coming from a CS background, I couldn't comprehend how '.contains()' query is done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ since the range is 1 to $n^2$ while your space complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n)$. And why do you loop up to  $n$ instead of $n^2$?

Comment: Thanks. Can we do it without using the Hash Sets.Both the algorithms shouldn't use Hash sets or any other advanced data structure. A and B are just arrays.

Comment: Insertions into a HashSet are O(1) average amortized time, under assumptions like perfect hashing and what not. Worse-case is O(n).

Part 1. is exactly the element uniqueness problem and has a provable lower-bound of O(n log n).

Comment: *addition* There are some restrictions that are likely the key to getting around the element-uniqueness lower bound, but the general case it isn't possible.

Comment: @Husarev The arrays have $n$ entries. Each entry is a number from the range $1$ to $n^2$. **Example:** Let $n=3$. A concrete problem case could be $A=[9, 9, 1]$ and $B=[2, 7, 5]$.

Comment: @D'Nabre So the question 1 can not be done in O(n). What about Q2?

Comment: @Socowi I see where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Socowi Can we do the Q2 with out using Hashset?

Comment: @D'Nabre: But this is not the general case. In this case, we have a clear bound for the size of the element values.

Answer (score 2):

The principle is similar to radix sort; then check uniqueness in each bucket.

- Prepare n lists of elements (buckets), initially empty
- For each element x:

  - Separate x into its two digits msd (most significant digit) and lsd in base n.
  - Append lsd to the end of the msd'th list
- Iterate through all buckets, check that each lsd in each list is unique. If not, some number x was added twice.

--

```
n = ...

def unique1(xs, seen):
  """Are the values of xs (0 to n-1) unique? O(len(xs))"""
  unique = True
  for x in xs:
    if seen[x]:
      unique = False
      break
    seen[x] = True
  # Clear seen[] for next run.
  for x in xs:
    seen[x] = False
  return unique

def unique2(xs):
  """Are the values of xs (0 to n^2-1) unique? O(n)"""

  # Sort xs into buckets by most significant digit. n buckets containing
  # len(xs) (= n) elements in total, so O(n) space.
  buckets = [[] for _ in range(n)]
  for x in xs:
    msd, lsd = divmod(x, n)
    buckets[msd].append(lsd)

  # Check uniqueness in each bucket. In total len(xs) values are passed to
  # unique1, so total O(n) time.
  temp = [False] * n
  for b in buckets:
    if not unique1(b, temp):
      return False

  return True
```

Edit: trivial to extend to second question by also storing the source of the element (set A or B) in the buckets.

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm in English so that people not conversant in python can understand it as well?

Comment: I have added an outline of the algorithm; but I think the Python code is already very close to pseudocode.

Comment: This algoritm is O(n^2), since `unique1` is O(n) instead of O(len(xs)). If you want to have a list `seen` of length `len(xs)`, you don't know where to put `True` for value `5` (for example). If you make a list of length `n`, initializing it takes O(n) time.

Comment: @styrofoamfly you're right. I hoisted `seen` up to reuse it across runs to avoid clearing it. What do you think?

Comment: @CatalinPatulea It seems like a good idea, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite simple if your values were all in the range 0 ≤ k < n: Create an array b of n boolean values initialised to all "false", then for each array element k check whether b [k] is true or false. If b [k] is true then there are duplicates, and if not then set b [k] = true.

Unfortunately, the values are from 0 to n^2 - 1.

For every j, 0 ≤ j < n, build a linked list of all array values k where k = j (modulo n). That can be done in O (n) time and space for all array elements, since all you need to do is initialise n empty lists, and add each array element to one of the lists.

Then for each linked list, use the method above to check whether the values floor (k / n), which are all in the range from 0 to n-1, are unique. The array b is initialised *once*. Then we check one linked list, and when we are done with that list, we set all elements of b corresponding to list elements back to false. That way the total time is again O (n), since the total number of items in all linked lists is exactly n.

The essential "trick" to not use more than O (n) time is to not initialise the array b each time (O (n), needs to be done n times), but set it to "all false" only once, and then just set those elements back to false that were set to true before.